# Query For Insert From Select Query

Tags: sql, select, create-table

I have a table named `tb_tweetkurator_test` and the query is:

```
SELECT id_user,
        COUNT(id_tweet) as JML_TWEET,
        COUNT(IF(url = 'yes', url, NULL)) as JML_TWEET_URL,
        COUNT(IF(mention = 'yes', mention, NULL)) as JML_TWEET_MENTION,
        COUNT(IF(retweet = 'yes', retweet, NULL)) as JML_TWEET_RETWEET,
        COUNT(IF(tweet_biasa = 'yes', tweet_biasa, NULL)) as JML_TWEET_BIASA
FROM tb_tweetkurator_test
GROUP BY id_user;
```

and the result is

```
id_user   | JML_TWEET | JML_TWEET_URL| JML_TWEET_MENTION | JML_TWEET_RETWEET | ML_TWEET_BIASA

16912985  | 20        | 6            | 13                | 0                 | 3
23343960  | 10        | 10           | 0                 | 0                 | 0
46651600  | 20        | 9            | 17                |15                 | 2
267164011 | 20        | 14           |10                 |4
```

What makes me confuse is, can I insert data above (from the `SELECT` query) into a new table?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You could either use the create-as-select to create a new table from this result set:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
SELECT id_user,
        COUNT(id_tweet) as JML_TWEET,
        COUNT(IF(url = 'yes', url, NULL)) as JML_TWEET_URL,
        COUNT(IF(mention = 'yes', mention, NULL)) as JML_TWEET_MENTION,
        COUNT(IF(retweet = 'yes', retweet, NULL)) as JML_TWEET_RETWEET,
        COUNT(IF(tweet_biasa = 'yes', tweet_biasa, NULL)) as JML_TWEET_BIASA
FROM tb_tweetkurator_test
GROUP BY id_user;
```

Or insert it to an existing table:

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT id_user,
        COUNT(id_tweet) as JML_TWEET,
        COUNT(IF(url = 'yes', url, NULL)) as JML_TWEET_URL,
        COUNT(IF(mention = 'yes', mention, NULL)) as JML_TWEET_MENTION,
        COUNT(IF(retweet = 'yes', retweet, NULL)) as JML_TWEET_RETWEET,
        COUNT(IF(tweet_biasa = 'yes', tweet_biasa, NULL)) as JML_TWEET_BIASA
FROM tb_tweetkurator_test
GROUP BY id_user;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `select/into` like this:

```
SELECT id_user,
        COUNT(id_tweet) as JML_TWEET,
        COUNT(IF(url = 'yes', url, NULL)) as JML_TWEET_URL,
        COUNT(IF(mention = 'yes', mention, NULL)) as JML_TWEET_MENTION,
        COUNT(IF(retweet = 'yes', retweet, NULL)) as JML_TWEET_RETWEET,
        COUNT(IF(tweet_biasa = 'yes', tweet_biasa, NULL)) as JML_TWEET_BIASA
INTO your_new_table
FROM tb_tweetkurator_test
GROUP BY id_user;
```